# Adding nuget package to ASP.NET MVC 6 project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package

Although they have not ended support for nuget package manager in ASP.NET 5 but -at least with javascript libraries- nuget does not seem to work anymore.

I tried (and failed) to add `React.ASPNET` library using nuget (as I didn't find it on Bower).

There is a reference added under `DNX 4.5.1` but no script file is added to `wwroot/lib` as it would when adding a JS library with Bower.

There's also no sign of it in the `project.json` dependencies.

It's an ASP.NET 5 project on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.ASPNET is a library which allows you do do something like that:

```
@Html.React("CommentsBox", new {
    initialComments = Model.Comments
})
```

It add some extension method to the ASP.NET MVC. You can also do something like that:

```
<!-- Initialise the component in JavaScript too -->
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

If you want to learn more take a look here: http://reactjs.net/

Comment: I knew I could reference CDN scripts but shouldn't the package manager add local copies when referencing a script library?

Comment: I thing not with React.ASPNET. Take a look here: http://reactjs.net/. There is full detailed tutorial.